# SSE where can I find a translation guide from SSE intrinsics to assembler

Tags: assembly, sse, intrinsics

I need to program some stuff in SSE2 assembler.
All I see though are intrinsics.

I've been looking in vain for a translation table from intrinsics to assembler.
Because I don't want to play a guessing game, can someone please give me a link to translate these awful intrinsics to pretty assembly.

I only need SSE/SSE2 integer instructions.

And please don't tell me to just use C(++) I don't have that option, nor do I want to.

Where can I get a translation guide?

**EDIT**
Thanks for the links, however I don't have a translation yet for the composite intrinsics, does anyone have link for that? It would really speed things up. :-)

Comment: MSDN has a quite complete list of them: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dh78ez%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (those are the exact same intrinsics that every other compiler supports too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intel documents are cumbersome. For a quick list check out AMD's SSEPlus project's [function table](http://sseplus.sourceforge.net/fntable.html).

Comment: this is a work of art, very informative and right to the point.

Answer (score 4):

One option, for the direction instruction => intrinsics, you can use *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual
Volume 2 (2A & 2B):
Instruction Set Reference, A-Z*, available at [Intel's website here](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/).

Direct link: http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/325383.pdf
The interesting part starts at page: 1618

Comment: Thanks Norbert, I had to use my last remnant of google-fu, but that's the sort of reference I as talking 'bout.